# My video div and other div are overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so I am making a portfolio site (I am a relatively new web student) and I am using elements of Bootstrap for my navbar.  That may be irrelevant to my question, but I have a video background as my landing page and my site is a scrolling site.  The problem I am having now is that my About page is under my video background landing page and I can't resize my page to mobile with out my video div and my about div to over lap or just stick together.  I tried using media queries but for some reason they are not working, I don't know if that is because bootstrap is not allowing it or if I am just doing my media queries are wrong?  If you could take a look at my code and help I would love you all forever, THANK YOU for any kind of help.

Also sorry if my code is excessive, this is my first time using Stackoverflow so I'm a n00b, I apologize.

```
enter code here <div class="hidden-phone">
                 <div class="header-unit">
                   <div id="video-container">
                    <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth" muted>
                      <source src="videos/homeVid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                      <source src="videos/homeVid.mov" type="video/mov" />
                      <source src="videos/homeVid.webm" type="video/webm" /> Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
                    </video>
                   </div>
                  <!-- end video-container -->
                    <img class="gif" src="images/CreateEveryDay.gif" />
                </div>
               <!-- end .header-unit -->
               </div>
               <!--end of header container-->
               <div id="belowVideo">
                 <div id="section">
                  <p> About </p>
                 </div>
                <div class="jumbotron">
                  <img src="images/PhillyBackgrounds.jpg" class="philly"/>
                  <img src="images/TylerPic.png" class="tylerPic"/>

                   <p class="bioHeader" style="font-size: 1.1em;">(Little bit about me)</p>
                   <p class="bio" class="hidden-phone" style="font-size: .9em;"> 
                My name is Tyler Reardon and I'm a UI/UX Designer with a mixed bag of skills from Philadelphia, PA. My daily goal is to cram as much great design into this world as I can, and enjoy every day that I do it. Im passionate about people and the human experience, and I try and convey that through my work. 
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    Thanks for checking me out. 
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    </p>
                  <div id="resumeCircle">
                   <a href="images/resume.pdf" target="_blank"><img class="resume" src="images/curriculum.png"/></a>
                    <br>
                   <p style="top: 130px; left: 25px"> Resume</p>

                  </div>

                </div>

               <div class="portfolioContainer">
              <div id="portfolio">
                <h1> Portfolio</h1> 
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

------------------STYLE SHEET-----------------------------

```
               header-unit {
                 height: 800px;
                 border-right:none;
                 border-left: none;
                 position: relative;
                 top: :0;
                 overflow: auto;
                 }

               #video-container {
                 }

              #video-container {
                top:0px;
                left:0%;
                height:100%%;
                 width:100%;
                overflow: auto;
                 }

              video {
                z-index:-1;
                filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
                 }

              video.fillWidth {
                width: 100%;
                 }


              #belowVideo {
                top:0%;
                position: absolute;
                 }

              .jumbotron {
                 margin-top: 5%;  
                 }

             .philly {
                 width: 100%;
                 left: 0%;
                 position: absolute;
                 margin-top: 0%;
                 }

             .tylerPic {
                 max-width: 45%;
                 min-width: 30%;
                 left: 22%;
                 position: absolute;
                 margin-top: 13%;
                 }


             .bioHeader {
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 10%;
                left: 34%;
                letter-spacing: 9px;
                background-color: #000;
                opacity: .5;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 20px;
                font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 300;
                }

              .bio {
                text-align: center;
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 35%;
                left: 11%;
                right: 15%;
                font-size: 50px;
                font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;  
                letter-spacing: 5px;
                font-weight: 300;
                padding: 40px;
                }

              #resumeCircle{
                position: absolute;
                left: 43%;
                background-color: #ff6600;
                border-radius: 50%;
                width: 130px;
                height: 130px;
                margin-top: 700px;
                opacity: .8;
                }

               .resume{
                position: absolute;
                width: 60px;
                height: auto;
                left: 35px;
                top: 20px;
                font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;  
                filter: #000;
                -webkit-filter: white;
                }


              .portfolioContainer {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                margin-top: 70em;
                }

              #portfolio {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                padding: 10px;
                }
```

Comment: `#belowVideo { top: 0%; }` That might be part of the issue.

Comment: It was thank you, I tend to put too much code when I can do things more simply.

Comment: Nice! I've made that comment into an answer, which you can vote on/accept if it was the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you have

```
#belowVideo {
  top: 0%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

which tells the browser to position that element at the top of the next parent element who is relatively positioned, no matter what else is there.

If you remove that block, the element will be free to move down under everything else in the way that your HTML defines it.